# ImportError: No module named discord raised even though I have already installed the module

Tags: python, discord.py

I have installed discord.py on vscode even though I have installed it, am I doing something wrong or missing something? As in all the videos I have watched on it, the module has worked.

Comment: have you gone into a command prompt and typed `pip install discord.py`?

Comment: What python version do you have installed and how does your code looks like?

Comment: I have installed it in command prompt

Comment: The version is 1.7.3 and this is my code:

Comment: `import discord
import os 
from dotenv import load_dotenv

client = discord.Client()

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('TOKEN')

client.run(TOKEN)`

Comment: Please run `pip --version`  in the command prompt and check if the python version it says in brackets is the same as the python version you use.

Comment: The version said in brackets is the same as the one I use

Comment: Discord.py only works with Python 3.5.3 or higher.

Comment: I am running it on 3.10.0 and it is not recognised as a module by vscode

Comment: I just reloaded it and it is now showing prompts for what I can type which it did not do before and is classing it as a module but when I run the code, it still throws the same `ImportError`